# Get button inside div javascript file

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on some MVC ASP .NET Project.

In my View folder i have a Dashoboard.cshtml file which include this part of code :

```html
  <div id="something">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Export To PDF</button>
    </div>
```

I attached a script to the file :

```
<script src="~/Content/Scripts/js/dashboard.js"></script>
```

I created onClick function in the javascript file which will open another view file , but something is not working in my code.

```
#("#something .button").on('click', function () {

//Do something...

})
```

Can i get some help ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: might be a typo. if you meant to use jQuery, it should be $(<query>) not #. Assuming you have jquery.

Comment: .button is looking for an element with the class 'button' you need: #somthing .btn-primary in your selector

Comment: There are some errors. It's not #, it's $ JQuery notation. And class .button doesn't exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jQuery class selector is wrong. And your'e using a `#` instead of `$` for jQuery.  Change the JS to the following.

```
$("#something .btn-primary").on('click', function () {

//Do something...

})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="something">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Export To PDF</button>
  </div>
 </body>
 <script>
   $("#something .btn").click( function () {
     console.log('do something')
   })
 </script>
</html>
```

1. you have to include jquery to use **$("#something .btn")** function
2. you should use **class name** or **id** to identify the element.

Answer (score -1):

Why to use script?

```
<div>
   <a class="btn btn-primary" href="@Url.Action("myFunction", "myControler")"></a>
</div>
```

myFunction is ActionResult function in myControler which calls View.